# I get a syntax error at line 4 (I know there excess lines rn)

Tags: ti-basic

```
Menu("RADIAN CONVERSION","DEGREE TO RADIAN",1,"RADIAN TO DEGREE",2
Lbl 1
Input "DEGREE=",C
C/180⯈Frac→W
Goto 3
Lbl 3
Goto 4
Lbl 2
Input "RADIAN=","LEAVE OUT PIE",A
A(180)→D
Goto 5
Lbl 4
Disp "RADIAN",P
Lbl 5
Disp "DEGREE=",D
Stop
```

The error is in line 4. I know there are easier ways to do this but I just wanna learn.

Comment: What is `` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the language of TI-BASIC, variables aren't stored as fractions; they are [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#:%7E:text=Some%20simple%20rational%20numbers%20(e.g.%2C%201/3%20and%201/10)%20cannot%20be%20represented%20exactly%20in%20binary%20floating%20point%2C%20no%20matter%20what%20the%20precision%20is.). When you want to display a variable as a fraction, use the `⯈Frac` command in the `Disp` command itself. Note that this does not automatically display later values as fractions. Here is some code with `//` to mark a comment at the end of the line.

```
Input "DEGREE=",D
180/D→R                  // R is not a fraction.

...

Lbl 4
Disp "RADIAN=",R⯈Frac    // TI-OS displays R as a fraction.

...

Disp "RADIAN=",R         // Will not display as a fraction.
Stop
```